# How can I open android video camera only HD mode?

Tags: android, video, video-capture

I want to open video camera with intent and take a video only HD mode.(Phone have Full HD, HD and TV(very low) mode). I just open video camera like above. But I cannot set any params in it.

```
Intent videoCapture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(videoCapture, 1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**MediaStore.class**

/**
     * The name of the Intent-extra used to control the quality of a recorded video. This is an
     * integer property. Currently value 0 means low quality, suitable for MMS messages, and
     * value 1 means high quality. **In the future other quality levels may be added.**
     */

```
public final static String EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY = "android.intent.extra.videoQuality";
```

I think there is no solution for now .s

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to set parameters for your video capture :

```
Intent videoCapture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        videoCapture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60); // Duration in Seconds
        videoCapture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); // Quality High (0 : Quality Low)
        videoCapture.putExtra(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.HEIGHT, 320);
        videoCapture.putExtra(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.WIDTH, 240);
```

You can find more informations on the [MediaStore page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore).

Hope it helps !

Comment: My phone have 3 type of video camera. FULL HD, HD and TV mode and I want to open HD mode video camera.

Comment: May be you can try different settings like 0, 1 and 2 and see what comes out.

Comment: You can also try to write your own video recorder and set the custom resolution you want : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera

Comment: EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY = 0  open 640*480   and EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY = 1,2,3,4  open  1920*1080       but HD is 1280*720 I cannot open HD mode with this way

Comment: I think you should try to write you own video recorde, that's the best way to control what you want to retrieve.